# exclude a folder and match all .html pattern files in a root folder using regex

Tags: php, regex

i need to write a regex which match all .html files from all the folder except images folder.

Below is format of html files

```
/magazines/sample.html 
/test/index.html
/test/format_ss1.html
/test/folder/newstyle_1.html
/images/two.html
```

i need to get only first 2 html files i.e., we are exluding files which ends with '_[0-9]' and '_ss[0-9]' and .hmtl files in images folder.

i have successfully done by excluding 3 and 4 but i can't able to excule .html files in images folder.

```
$regex = '/[a-zA-Z0-9\-][^_ss\d][^_\d]+\.html/'; //this will do for 3 and 4 files
```

but i need to exlude images folder..

i have tried like

```
$regex = '/[^images\/][a-zA-Z0-9\-][^_ss\d][^_\d]+\.html/'; // not working
```

can some one help me out this..

Answer (score 2):

Have a try with:

```
~^(?!/images/)[a-zA-Z0-9/-]+(?!_ss\d|\d)\.html$~
```

**in action:**

```
$arr = array(
'/magazines/sample.html',
'/test/index.html',
'/test/format_ss1.html',
'/test/folder/newstyle_1.html',
'/images/two.html'
);
foreach($arr as $str) {
    if (preg_match('~^(?!/images/)[a-zA-Z0-9/-]+(?!_ss\d|\d)\.html$~', $str))
        echo $str,"\n";
}
```

**output:**

```
/magazines/sample.html
/test/index.html
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But It is listing all .html files.. :(

Comment: i Have tried but no... it is including images folder too... :( Actually we are using this in migrate stuff in Drupal7

Comment: @BhanuPrakash: How do you use it? I add a test that shows it working.

Comment: yes. Above code is working file. But i don't know why it is not working in migration(custom migration script in Drupal 7)..anyways.. thanq very much for your answer

Comment: @BhanuPrakash: Sorry, I don't get you.

Comment: Very nice and complete answer +1